# How I can turn on and off BlockHound check

Tags: java, spring, blockhound

I have some App with WebFlux and i want to use BlockHound, but i need to have a possible turn on and off it through parameter in application.properties or through spring profiling or somthing else.
Also I want to override action, when the lock operation is caught so that not throw error but log warning. And firstly, i did through parameter in application.properties:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class GazPayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            ConfigurableApplicationContext context =
                    SpringApplication.run(GazPayApplication.class, args);
            BlockHoundSwitch blockHoundSwitch = (BlockHoundSwitch)context.getBean("BlockHoundSwitchBean");
            if (blockHoundSwitch.isBlockHoundEnabled()) {
                BlockHound.install(builder ->
                        builder.blockingMethodCallback(it ->
                                log.warn("find block operation: {}", it.toString())));
    }
}
```

And my BlockHoundSwitch:

```
@Component("BlockHoundSwitchBean")
@Getter
public class BlockHoundSwitch {
    @Value("${blockhound.enabled}")
    private boolean blockHoundEnabled;
}
```

It works for me but in my opinion this solution quite difficult and a little unpredictable.
Next i tried resolve this task through profiling:

```
@Profile("blockhound_enabled")
@Slf4j
@Component()
public class BlockHoundSwitch {

    public BlockHoundSwitch() {
        BlockHound.install(builder ->
                builder.blockingMethodCallback(it ->
                        log.warn("find block operation: {}", it.toString())));
    }
}
```

And it works too. Well, I have a few questions:

1. Which way is better, why and maybe there is another solution?
2. I need to localize and log, where block operation happened. How can I get class name and method, where it`s happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve it. Maybe someone it will be useful. I did it through profiling and my code bellow:

```
@Profile("blockhound_on")
@Slf4j
@Component()
@Getter
public class BlockHoundSwitch {

    public BlockHoundSwitch() {
        BlockHound.install(builder ->
                builder.blockingMethodCallback(it -> {
                    List<StackTraceElement> itemList = Arrays.stream(new Exception(it.toString()).getStackTrace())
                            .filter(i -> i.toString().contains("application.package"))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    log.warn("find block operation: \n{}", itemList);
                }));
    }
}
```

where application.package - main package of my project, which i`m finding in stacktrace.